# Post-build step for multiple targets

Tags: makefile, post-build-event

I have a makefile that has multiple targets for outputting data in different formats, e.g. `make html`, `make pdf`, `make txt` etc. and I would like to have pre-build and post-build steps that run when any of these options are used. I have the pre-build step sorted, but not sure how I can get the post-build step working properly.

```
.PHONY: html pdf txt pre-build post-build

pre-build:
    do-pre-build-stuff

post-build:
    do-post-build-stuff

html: data.dat
    generate-html data.dat

pdf: data.dat
    generate-pdf data.dat

txt: data.dat
    generate-txt data.dat

data.dat: pre-build
    generate-some-data > data.dat
```

How can I get the `post-build` step to run after every target?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to write a different rule for each one, unfortunately.  But you can make it simpler with a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html):

```
html pdf txt: %: real-%
        do-post-build-stuff

real-html: data.dat
        generate-html data.dat

real-pdf: data.dat
        generate-pdf data.dat

real-txt: data.dat
        generate-txt data.dat
```

This creates targets `html`, `pdf`, and `txt` which depend on the `real-` versions.  The `real-` versions do the actual work, then after they're done the post-build stuff is done as a recipe in the base target (`html`, `pdf`, and `txt`).

That rule is just a shorthand so you don't have to write it all out; the result is identical:

```
html: real-html
        do-post-build-stuff

pdf: real-pdf
        do-post-build-stuff

txt: real-txt
        do-post-build-stuff
```

Comment: That looks promising, will try in a moment. Could you please explain what's happening on the first line?

Comment: I added a pointer to the make docs describing static pattern rules and a bit of info.

Comment: Why can't `do-post-build-stuff` be its own recipe and called after the prerequisites are fulfilled?

Comment: How would it be "called"?  Rules are not functions.  The recipe of a rule is invoked after all the prerequisites are completed (if the target needs to be updated).  Here they want to run `make pdf` and build just the PDF, then also `do-post-build-stuff`.