# Ensure Post-Build Step Runs

Tags: makefile

I apologize if this has been asked before, I just started messing with Makefiles today.

So I am attempting to use a Makefile to import and drop a test database before/ after a set of tests run.  Currently both steps run, however the post-test step will only run if there were no problems running the tests.

```
REPORTER = nyan

.PHONY: test

pre-test:
    echo "PRE STUFF"

test: pre-test
    @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
        ./test \
        --recursive \
        --reporter $(REPORTER)

post-build: test
    echo "AFTER STUFF"
```

How I understand it is the syntax works like this:

`<task> : <task prereq's>`

I guess the issue is that one of the steps appears to "fail" to `make`, so it doesn't continue?

Comment: Also see [How to run pre- and post-recipes for every target using GNU Make?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37952098/608639) and [Post-build step for multiple targets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017069/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence *however the post-test even will only run if there were no problems running the tests* doesn't really parse.  It's helpful if you clearly state what the behavior you want is, and the clearly describe what behavior you get.

Also, I'm assuming for the above makefile you're running `make post-build` otherwise only `pre-test` will run...?

You're correct, if the prerequisite of a target fails then the target itself won't be run by make.

For the above example I recommend you put the pre and post steps into the same recipe.  If they are complex and you want to use them in multiple rules, you can put the commands into variables:

```
PRE-TEST = echo "PRE STUFF"
POST-TEST = echo "AFTER STUFF"

test:
        $(PRE-TEST)
        @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
            ./test \
            --recursive \
            --reporter $(REPORTER); \
         result=$$?; \
         $(POST-TEST); \
         exit $$result
```

Comment: I meant if tests fail, the post step doesn't run.  If the tests exit without errors, it would run the last step (although after running a successful test, I do believe I was wrong in that assumption).  Your solution does work though, thanks!

Comment: I think 'even' was confusing - replaced it with 'step'.