# How to run pre- and post-recipes for every target using GNU Make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

In `make`, is it possible to define a pre- and post-recipe for every target?

I want to (implicitly) insert the pre-recipe just above the first line of the explicit recipe and then (implicitly) insert the post-recipe after the last line in the explicit recipe.

It would be pretty easy to do it using regular expressions to insert lines but implicit ones would be so much cleaner.

Comment: Do you want the same pre-recipe for all targets? And the same post-recipe for all targets?

Comment: @Beta yes. Otherwise, if the pre- and post- is unique to each target then you might as well just paste it in the recipe in the first place.

Comment: My thought exactly, I just wanted to be sure that was what you meant. I know of no way to do what you want, short of having the makefile edit itself.

Comment: @Beta ok thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: Would `target: pre-target target-impl post-target` be the sort of thing you mean?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode yes that's correct.

Comment: @Adrian Ayyyy I'll give it an answer then

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a special helper shell that executes the desired pre- and post- actions before and after its input script and tell `make` to use that shell for executing the recipes (use the [`SHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell) variable to that end).

Besides, if you are using multiline recipes, you will have to enable the [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell) mode.

> **Caveat**: in this mode a failed command (except the last one) doesn't fail
>   the rule, so you either have to join the commands with `&&`, or append
>   `|| exit 1` to the end of each command, or run the real shell with the `-e`
>   option.

Example:

**pre-post-shell**

```
#!/bin/bash

preaction()
{
    echo "Pre-action"
}

postaction()
{
    echo "Post-action"
}

preaction && /bin/bash "$@" && postaction
```

**makefile**

```
SHELL=./pre-post-shell

all: Hello Bye

.ONESHELL:

Hello:
    @echo Hello
    echo Hello again

Bye:
    @echo Bye
```

Output:

```
$ make
Pre-action
Hello
Hello again
Post-action
Pre-action
Bye
Post-action
```

Comment: So the helper shell is just a bash script yes?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, yes, yes (short comments are not allowed)

Comment: using your same strategy, is it also possible to execute a static recipe before and/or after each LINE in recipe?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, simply don't use the `.ONESHELL` mode

Comment: To what program does the `-e` apply? I looked at [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html) but there's no `-e` and [GNU make `-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) is about environment overrides.??

Comment: @Adrian `-e` is an option of bash. It is documented in the [set builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin) section (since all of the single-character options used with the set builtin can be used as options when the shell is invoked)

Comment: Is there any reason, whether for my simple case or otherwise, why I'd use `-e` vs the `&&`-ing or `|| exit 1`-ing of statements? All equally valid?

Comment: In complicated bash scripts usage of `-e` may lead to unexpected behaviour. The other two methods are safe.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a target that you call using the `$(MAKE)` command on the same file making the call:

```
THIS_FILE:=$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

SOURCES:=main.cpp other.cpp
OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

OUT:=main

.PHONY: all pre post

all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(OUT) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

pre:
    @echo "PRE TARGET"

post:
    @echo "POST TARGET"

%.o: pre %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(lastword $^) -o $@
    @$(MAKE) -f $(THIS_FILE) post
```

This example Makefile will output something like:

```
PRE TARGET
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -g -c main.cpp -o main.o
POST TARGET
PRE TARGET
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -g -c other.cpp -o other.o
POST TARGET
g++ -o main main.o other.o
```

Comment: Yes it works but the question asks for "implicit rule" meaning I define the pre- and post-rule and maybe some other flags in `make` and then `make` automatically inserts the pre- and post-rules as it's executing the recipes. As I stated in question, I know I could use regex to efficiently insert the execution of `pre` and `post` into existing makefile targets. If this option doesn't exist then that's fine. Write that as the answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Plus one for giving me idea on calling a specific target in the existing makefile. If there's no built-in option I'll just end up calling `pre` at the beginning the same way you called `post`

Comment: @Adrian I'm fairly certain this is the only way to have a rule be a pre-requisite and another a post-requisite.