# GNU Make - how to add timestamp output (with minimal makefile modification)

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I want to get a better idea of my build job metrics but unfortunately, `make` doesn't output timestamps per se.

If I run `make --print-data-base`, for a given target it outputs a line

```
#  Last modified 2016-08-15 13:53:16
```

but that doesn't give me the duration.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to get duration of building a target without modifying each target? Some targets are inside makefiles which are generated DURING the build so not feasible to modify their recipes.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I could [implement a pre- and post-recipe for every target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952098/gnu-make-how-to-run-pre-and-post-recipes-for-every-target) and output a timestamp that way.

Is that a good idea given this is parallel `make`? Obviously there would be increased build time from calling a pre- and post-recipe for every target but I'd be fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a parallel make, then the "preactions", "actions" and "postactions" may be interleaved. That is, you might get output like:

```
Pre-action 12:03:05
Pre-action 12:03:06
building foo...
building bar...
Post-action 12:04:17
Post-action 12:04:51
```

So it would behoove you to pass a TARGETNAME variable to the pre-action and post-action scripts.

Also, start and end times are not all there is to know about how long an action takes, when you are running things in parallel; rule A might take longer that rule B, simply because rule B is running alone while rule A is sharing the processor with rules C through J.

Other than that, I see no problem with this approach.

Comment: `SHELL` can be redefined as a recursively expanded variable, so `SHELL = my-script $@` could be a clean way to pass the target name. Also, setting `.SHELLFLAGS` to empty is probably a good idea.

Comment: If you're bored, I made an [offshoot question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086951/gnu-make-parallel-how-to-record-idle-vs-active-time-for-a-job)