# GNU Make parallel - how to record idle vs active CPU time for a job

Tags: windows, multithreading, makefile, benchmarking, gnu-make

I'm using `make --jobs=<num>` to do parallel builds on a multi-core  machine.

I want to have a robust method to record how long it takes for a given target to get built using the [pre-action, build, post-action model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000279/4784683).

[This answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084238/4784683):

> Also, start and end times are not all there is to know about how long
>   an action takes, when you are running things in parallel; rule A might
>   take longer that rule B, simply because rule B is running alone while
>   rule A is sharing the processor with rules C through J.

Therefore, in order to have a accurate 'duration to build a target', I have to record the worker thread's percentage of time active and multiply that by the recorded duration of a target to get real duration.

Running `make` with `--trace` - and `--jobs` of course - gives a bunch of these statements whose mapping to OS thread IDs I'm unsure of

```
Main thread handle = 00000098
```

I need to be able to map an OS thread ID to a `make` `thread handle`

**QUESTIONS**

1. Are these `thread handle`s internal to `make` or do they correspond to OS thread IDs that I could profile with [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?
2. How do I go from `make`'s `thread handle`s to OS thread IDs?

**UPDATE**

@Kaz makes a good point about prerequisites: what if some or all or none are made?
Answer: I will take care of that in my parsing of the output. Since I'm `make`ing with `--print-data-base` I can parse how much of the time spent to build a target was due to target itself vs its prerequisites.

Comment: > *I want to have a robust method to record how long it takes for a given target to get built.* From what state? Under a complete rebuild, or incremental? How much of the prerequisite graph for the target can be missing? From when do you measure this time: from the time you type `make ...`? From the time the first pre-requisite for the target is kicked off?

Comment: @Kaz for each target; [see this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38000279/4784683)

Comment: @Kaz I see your point about prerequisites. I'm going to parse the output file so I'll take care of how to account for prereqs.

Comment: If you want a pre/post actions that time the build recipe, you basically have to put it into the recipe, no via external shell scripts.  Say, a macro invoked as `$(call TIME,$@,$(CC) -o $@ ...)` or whatever. First argument is the target, then the second is the shell command to build it. When in timing mode, `TIME` can run the command under `time`, parse the output and add to some report.

Comment: I like this question; it would be useful to hack on something like this on a rainy day.

Comment: @Kaz I agree modifying the recipe would be ideal but many of my makefiles are auto-generated by `qmake` but even if they weren't, I'd still like a solution that doesn't modify the makefile.

Comment: @Kaz besides being kludgy and adding overhead, is there anything wrong with the shell solution?

Comment: Builds aren't usually purely CPU-bound.  There's usually an I/O component as well, unless you have *really* fast disks.  With SSDs, I/O parallelism usually only helps (but doesn't scale perfectly).  With magnetic disks, seeking is slow.  So this is an extra confounding factor.

Comment: @PeterCordes my build is CPU-bound. With `--jobs=4` on my 4/8 core machine, after a few secs, my CPUs are maxed out. But yes that's a good point which is "easily" accounted for: using ProcMon, you can record whether a thread is idle bc of swapping or because of I/O.

Comment: @PeterCordes Total Time = CPU active + CPU idle (I/O bound) + CPU idle (thread switching)

Comment: It's harder to account for the lack of repeatability caused by disk cache being hot or cold.  Of course, during a normal edit/build/debug cycle, it's mostly the repeated rebuilds that you want to optimize, so only worrying about the hot-caches case makes sense.  But my point was that maybe a different build rule for one target uses less CPU but more I/O, and that's actually a bigger impact on the rest of the build.

Comment: @Adrian Without changing the Makefile or make utility, what comes to mind is oeprating system process accounting.

Comment: @PeterCordes that will all be taken into account. Both the start to stop time along with the active CPU time will be recorded for every target.